# Flutter project closes in emulator after clicking login api button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

```
onCancelled at PHASE_CLIENT_ANIMATION_CANCEL
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher( 4588): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=ImeCallback=ImeOnBackInvokedCallback@205512508 Callback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@165a0d4
D/AndroidRuntime( 4588): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 4588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4588): Process: com.slaylewks, PID: 4588
E/AndroidRuntime( 4588): java.lang.SecurityException: com.slaylewks: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
```

I tried to call the login API to get OTP but the app closes after login button is clicked.

Expectation: It should navigate to OTP page where I get submit my OTP to proceed to home page

Comment: attach the code snippet plz